# Check if Sections/Options exist when using `CWinApp::GetProfileString()`

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Unlike the `WriteProfileString` method, the `GetProfileString` method does not offer a way to check if a section or an option even exists in the profile. All I can get is a default string. I am trying to implement a class representing my profile and I would like to have a

```
BOOL HasSection(CString sSection)
```

and a

```
BOOL HasOption(CString sSection, CString sOption)
```

method in it.

Comment: You probablement need to implement this by yourself by reading the registry (or if you are using .ini files by parsing the .ini file yourself which is pretty straightforward).

Comment: True, but only with a loss of generality. If Microsoft changes the way the profile strings are saved, I have to adapt those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to do. Please read the [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724366%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) carefully. Notice that when you pass NULL to first or a second parameter, the function returns a list of all section names (in the former case) or keys (in the latter case).

So for you to implement HaseOption() method you would have a code similar to this one:

```
BOOL HasSection(CString sSection)
{
    DWORD dwSize = 100, dwRequired;
    LPTSTR lpBuffer = new TCHAR[dwSize];
    BOOL bExists = FALSE;

    dwRequired = ::GetProfileString(NULL, NULL, _T(""), lpBuffer, dwSize);
    while(dwRequired == dwSize - 2)
    {
        // buffer is too small
        delete [] lpBuffer;

        dwSize = dwRequired + 100;
        lpBuffer = new TCHAR[dwSize];
        dwRequired = ::GetProfileString(NULL, NULL, _T(""), lpBuffer, dwSize);
    }
    if(dwRequired)
    {
        LPTSTR lpszFound = lpBuffer;
        do
        {
            if(sSection.CompareNoCase(lpszFound) == 0)
            {
                bExists = TRUE; break;
            }
        } while(*(lpszFound = _tcsninc(lpszFound, _tcsnbcnt(lpszFound, dwRequired)+1)));
    }
    delete [] lpBuffer;
    return bExists;
}
```

I have not tested the code, just cut-n-pasted from my program and modified a bit. Please test the code yourself

Comment: Thanks cha! Your code was extremely helpful! It just had a small bug: `_tcsinc` didn't iterate through all options but through all characters of the first option. I fixed that by modifying the condition in the do-while loop.